# The meaning of "invent the spitting crack of a “screw-cannon."

Tags: meaning

The very improbability of billiards in a dâk-bungalow proved the reality of the thing. No man—drunk or sober—could imagine a game at billiards, or **invent the spitting crack of a “screw-cannon.** ”A severe course of dâk-bungalows has this disadvantage—it breeds infinite credulity.

This is from 'MY OWN TRUE GHOST STORY' by Rudyard Kipling.   
https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2806/2806-h/2806-h.htm#link2H_4_0002

I can not understand the meaning of the sentence.  
invent the spitting crack of a “screw-cannon.

Comment: *Screw cannon* is a technique of striking a ball in billiards (https://www.lexico.com/definition/screw_cannon) [cannon means any type of strike or rebound]

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Given that he's talking about billiards in this passage, probably the billiards move.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey could it be both? I can't explain "the spitting crack" in billiards terms (or why it is "spitting")

Answer (score 2):

Here is another quote from that story

> Next minute I heard the double click of a cannon and my hair sat up. It is a mistake to say that hair stands up. The skin of the head tightens and you can feel a faint, prickly, bristling all over the scalp. That is the hair sitting up.

This suggests that in this passage Kipling is using *cannon* in the sense of a shot in which the cue ball strikes both the other balls (the red and the opponent's cue ball). Given that a *screw* is a shot where you impart sufficient back spin on the cue ball that it comes backwards after striking the (first) ball it hits it would seem that a *screw-cannon* must be a shot involving both phenomena.

A comment elsewhere by @Type1A states that this is called *carom* in the US rather than *cannon* (or *billiard*). Who would have thought that such an inherently simple game needed variant terminology on both sides of the Atlantic.

Comment: With this second quote you found, I think you must be right about the cannon. Nicely done. I don't know why the terminology is so different either. I only know U.K. terms from watching snooker. Potting vs. pocketing, in-off vs. scratch, double vs. bank, break-off vs. break (break having its own different meaning in Br.E), etc...

Answer (score 1):

Your text is talking about a game of billiards.

In billiards, a 'screw cannon' is a technique in which the player puts backspin on the cue ball by striking it below the centre, causing it to move backwards after hitting the object ball.

The "spitting crack" refers to the sound it makes - although I can't be sure if they refer to the sound of the cue striking the cue ball, or the balls striking together.

Comment: I'm a competitive billiards player: this term is antiquated in both Br.E and Am.E cue sports jargon. Nowadays it's just "screw" (Br.E) or "draw" (Am.E). The crack probably refers to the cue strike with the cue ball. You can pull up any "cue power" video on the Internet to hear the characteristic sound of a well-delivered draw / "deep screw" shot.

Comment: @TypeIA in my experience in the UK a _cannon_ is where you cause your cue ball to strike both the red and the opponent's ball thus scoring two points. We use _screw_ as you suggest.

Comment: @mdewey quite right... in Am.E this is a "carom" or "billiard" shot (depending on the order of contact between cue ball, object ball and pocketed ball in pocket games if not the object ball). I don't think this is the same "cannon" meant in this text, but could be wrong.

Comment: @TypeIA Since the passage is from Kipling, "antiquated" is no surprise.